# Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewValue

Tags: errors

Why do I get an

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewValue.
```

error for this entry:

```
@Misc{TSG-SA-WG3-44-Apr,
  Title                    = {{3GPP TSG SA WG3 (Security) meeting #44 S3-060541, Agenda Item: Industry Initiative to Withdraw A5/2}},
  Author                   = {{GSM Association Security Group}},
  Note                     = {Abgerufen am 05.04.2016},
  Url                      = {http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/tsg_sa/WG3_Security/TSGS3_44_Tallinn/Docs/S3-060541.zip},
  Year                     = {2006}
}
```

Working example is below

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    headings=small,
    parskip=half,           % Ersetzt manuelles setzten von parskip/parindent.
    bibliography=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot,       % Entfernt den letzten Punkt der Kapitelnummern.
    open=any,               % Kapitel kann auf jeder Seite beginnen.
%   final                   % Entfernt alle todonotes und den Entwurfstempel.
    ]{scrreprt}

% ===================================Praeambel==================================

% Kodierung, Sprache, Patches {{{
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Ausgabekodierung; ermoeglicht Akzente und Umlaute
                            %  sowie korrekte Silbentrennung.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Erlaub die direkte Eingabe spezieller Zeichen.
                            %  Utf8 muss die Eingabekodierung des Editors sein.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsche Sprachanpassungen (z.B. Ueberschriften).

% Gaensefuesschen auf Deutsch umstellen
%\usepackage[babel=once]{csquotes}
%\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
%\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}

\usepackage{microtype}      % Optimale Randausrichtung und Skalierung.
\usepackage[
    autostyle,
    ]{csquotes}             % Korrekte Anfuehrungszeichen in der Literaturliste.
% \usepackage{fixltx2e}       % Patches fuer LaTeX2e.
% \usepackage{scrhack}        % Verhindert Warnungen mit aelteren Paketen.
% }}}

% Schriftarten {{{
\usepackage{mathptmx}       % Times. Package 'times.sty' is obsolete.
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
% }}}

% Biblatex {{{
 \usepackage[
     style=alphabetic,
     backend=biber,
     backref=true
     ]{biblatex}             % Biblatex mit alphabetischem Style und biber.
 \addbibresource{resources/Literatur.bib}% Dateiname der bib-Datei.
 \AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}} % Keine Angabe der verwendeten Sprache
% }}}

% Dokument- und Texteinstellungen {{{
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    margin=2.54cm,
    marginparwidth=2.0cm,
    footskip=1.0cm
    ]{geometry}             % Ersetzt 'a4wide'.
\clubpenalty=10000          % Keine Einzelzeile am Beginn eines Paragraphen
                            %  (Schusterjungen).
\widowpenalty=10000         % Keine Einzelzeile am Ende eines Paragraphen
\displaywidowpenalty=10000  %  (Hurenkinder).
\usepackage{floatrow}       % Zentriert alle Floats.
\usepackage{ifdraft}        % Ermoeglicht \ifoptionfinal{true}{false}
\pagestyle{plain}           % keine Kopfzeilen
% \sloppy                     % großzügige Formatierungsweise
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\ } % Verbessert Layout mehrzeiliger Fußnoten

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{%
        pdftitle = {\@title},
        pdfauthor  = {\@author},
        pdfcreator   = {\@author},
        pdfproducer  = {\@author},
%       plainpages   = false,
%       pdfpagelabels = true,
        pdfdisplaydoctitle=true, % display document title instead of file name
        bookmarksnumbered = true
    }
}
\makeatother
% }}}

% Weitere Pakete {{{
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Einfuegen von Graphiken.
\usepackage{tabu}           % Einfuegen von Tabellen.
\usepackage{multirow}       % Tabellenzeilen zusammenfassen.
\usepackage{multicol}       % Tabellenspalten zusammenfassen.
\usepackage{booktabs}       % Schönere Tabellen (\toprule\midrule\bottomrule).
\usepackage[nocut]{thmbox}  % Theorembox bspw. fuer Angreifermodell.
\usepackage{amsmath}        % Erweiterte Handhabung mathematischer Formeln.
\usepackage{amssymb}        % Erweiterte mathematische Symbole.
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[
    printonlyused
    ]{acronym}              % Abkuerzungsverzeichnis.
\usepackage[
    colorinlistoftodos,
    textsize=tiny,          % Notizen und TODOs - mit der todonotes.sty von
    \ifoptionfinal{disable}{}%  Benjamin Kellermann ist das Package „changebar"
    ]{todonotes}            %  bereits integriert.
\usepackage[
    breaklinks,
    hidelinks,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle,
    pdfpagemode = {UseOutlines},
    pdfpagelabels,
    ]{hyperref}             % Sprungmarken im PDF. Laedt das URL Paket.
    \urlstyle{rm}           % Entfernt die Formattierung von URLs.
%\usepackage{breakurl}
%\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage{listings}       % Spezielle Umgebung für...
    \lstset{                %  ...Quelltextformatierung.
        language=C,
        breaklines=true,
        breakatwhitespace=true,
        frame=L,
        captionpos=b,
        xleftmargin=6ex,
        tabsize=4,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!50!black},
        commentstyle=\itshape\color{magenta!90!black},
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        stringstyle=\color{orange!90!black},
        showstringspaces=false,
        }
% }}}

% =========================Eigene packages und commands=========================
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand{\grayrow}{\rowcolor[gray]{.90}}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\shorthandoff{"} %Gaensefuesschen vor Vokal nicht zu Umlaut

\usepackage{hyperref}
%\end{fold_1}

% ===================================Dokument===================================

\title{XXXXXX}
\author{XXXXXXX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Aufgabenstellung}

Blabla

\cite{TSG-SA-WG3-44-Apr}


% =============================Literaturverzeichnis=============================
\chapter{Literaturverzeichnis}
\begin{raggedright}% schaltet Blocksatz ab, erzeugt ein stimmigeres Schriftbild im Literaturverzeichnis
\printbibliography % falls Biblatex verwendet wird
\end{raggedright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please expand this to a minimal working example.

Comment: @DBRN: Those are not *examples*... they're huge walls of text. Reduce the content to a manageable set that replicates the problem, and only the problem... not all of your document. That most surely means just one bibliography element, and not *everything*.

Comment: You can use that one single entry as an example. The rest of the bib file was just-in-case

Comment: I spent 15 minutes replacing everything that is not needed. thanks for downvoting

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!!  Please post the [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Please include the code in your question as readable text,  don't use links. When you have pasted the code,  select it and press `{}` to apply proper formatting. Keep in mind that the code must have all the packages needed for others to run it. If it gives an error, it's ok, that's what this site is for,  but we shouldn't be guessing what packages you loaded.

Comment: Is that ok (see original post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry `Faer2014` has both a `Date` and a `Year` field; remove one of them, preferably `Date`.

Some other entries have unescaped `#` characters: edit them to be like

```
@Misc{TSG-SA-WG3-44-Jul,
  Title                    = {Draft Report of SA3 meeting \#44},
  Author                   = {{Secretary of 3GPP TSG-SA WG3}},
  Note                     = {Abgerufen am 05.04.2016},
  Url                      = {http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/tsg_sa/WG3_Security/TSGS3_44_Tallinn/Report/S3-060772.zip},
  Year                     = {2006}
}
```

with `\#` instead of `#`.

After these changes, your example files run smoothly.

Comment: Could you perhaps recommend me a highlighter for special characters in a .bib file? Neither Jabref nor Texmaker does the job